# JpaRepository и контроллер

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Возник такой вопрос: У меня есть контроллер и в нём реализованы 2 метода - загрузка(addSong) и скачивание(getSong) файлов.
С загрузкой файлов на сервер всё нормально, проблема в скачивание. При попытки найти в БД запись по id(integer) я получаю Entity с пустыми свойствами и по итогу не могу скачать файл. Я пытался исправить это, но не получалось. По итогу в методе addSong я добавил строчку кода, которая читает все записи таблицы в БД(readAll) и больше ничего не изменял. После этого по id я получаю нужную мне Entity со всеми его значениями. Чем может быть обусловлено такое поведение?

Код контроллера:

```
@Controller
public class SongController {

    private final SongDataServices context;

    public SongController(SongDataServices context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String homePage(){
        return "home";
    }

    @Value("${upload.path}")
    private String uploadPath;

    @GetMapping("/getSong/{id}")
    public void getSong(@PathVariable int id, HttpServletResponse response){

        var t = context.readAll();

        Song song = null;
        song = context.read(id);
        if (song == null)
            return;
        else {
            String fileName = song.getUrl();
            Path file = Paths.get(fileName);
            if (Files.exists(file)){
                response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
                response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");


                try {
                    Files.copy(file, response.getOutputStream());
                    response.getOutputStream().flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //LOG.info("Error writing file to output stream. Filename was '{}'" + fileName, e);
                    throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
                }
            }

        }

    }

    @PostMapping("/addSong")
    public String addSong(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        if (file !=null){
            File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath);

            if(!uploadDir.exists()){
                uploadDir.mkdir();
            }

            String uuidFile = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            String resultFileName = uuidFile + "." + file.getOriginalFilename();

            String absoluteFileName = uploadPath + "/" + resultFileName;
            file.transferTo(new File(absoluteFileName));

            var temp =new Song();
            temp.setTitle(resultFileName);
            temp.setUrl(absoluteFileName);

            context.create(temp);
        }

        return "Answer";
    }
}
```

Код SongDataServices:

```
@Service
public class SongDataServices implements IDataService<Song> {

    protected final SongRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public SongDataServices(SongRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public void create(Song song) {
        repository.save(song);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Song> readAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Song read(int id) {
        return repository.getOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(Song client, int id) {
        if (repository.existsById(id)) {
            client.setId(id);
            repository.save(client);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(int id) {
        if (repository.existsById(id)) {
            repository.deleteById(id);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Код SongRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface SongRepository extends JpaRepository<Song, Integer> {
}
```

Код MvcConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${upload.path}")
    private String uploadPath;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/mp3/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file://" + uploadPath + "/");
    }
}
```

Код Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "songs")
public class Song {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    private String title;
    private String author;
    private int year;
    private String duration;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    public int userId;

    public String url;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы получаете entity с пустыми свойствами, потому что метод `JpaRepository.getOne()` - returns a reference to the entity with the given identifier (из api docs). Этот метод нужен для того, чтобы связать одну сущность с другой, доставая из базы только идентификатор. Для того, чтобы получить всю сущность используйте метод `findById()`.

Comment: Всё получилось с findById(). Большое спасибо за подсказку @notaProgrammer !